# Geometric Series and other Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

I am currently taking a class that assumes background with the mentioned. The class is "Intro to Probability." I however am not quite comfortable with them and wish to re learn the basics and identities. Does anyone know of a resource that would be of help? Perhaps a good book, online resource (preferably not wikipedia), etc. that would be of use to me?

Comment: Coursera has good intro stuff on probability

Comment: Maybe my old handouts "seq-and-series.pdf" (roughly U.S. high school algebra 2 level) and "geom-growth.pdf" (roughly U.S. high school precalculus level) will help, which you can find [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6544585).

Comment: I just wanted to let you know they helped a lot! Thanks a bunch!